# How to pass variable name instead of method name in python

Tags: python, google-places-api, variable-assignment

I'm using [Google Places API](https://github.com/slimkrazy/python-google-places) code to get the places and its details so in that code I want to pass variable name instead of its attribute type

Here is the snippet

> WORKS FINE

```
query_result = google_places.nearby_search(
        location='London, England', keyword='Fish and Chips',
        radius=20000, types=[types.TYPE_FOOD])
```

> GIVES ERROR

```
place_type='TYPE_FOOD'
query_result = google_places.nearby_search(
            location='London, England', keyword='Fish and Chips',
            radius=20000, types=[types.place_type])
```

`AttributeError: module 'googleplaces.types' has no attribute 'place_type'`

Any suggestion on how can it be done?

Thanks

Domnick

Comment: use only the types that are mentioned over here https://github.com/slimkrazy/python-google-places/blob/master/googleplaces/types.py

Comment: Still after using `place_type='TYPE_PARK'` from the link you provided, gives output for other types places like for `atm`, `bank`, `cafe` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getattr`

1) If TYPE_FOOD is a property you can use:

```
getattr(types, place_type)
```

2) If TYPE_FOOD is a method, you should call it:

```
getattr(types, place_type)()
```

Note: I am assuming that your method takes no arguments.

Comment: using `place_type='TYPE_BUS_STATION' query_result = google_places.nearby_search(
            location=str(latLNG[z]).replace('(','').replace(')',''), 
            radius=700, types=getattr(types, place_type))` gives output for all type like for `atm`, for `food`, for `school` etc. and not just for `BUS_STATION`